# Why would users want to submit a transaction directly to a specific miner?

Tags: mining-pools, mempool, relay, blockspace-market

I am wondering **why** some users are interested to send their Bitcoin transactions to a specific miner? This should increase the delay because of waiting for the specific miner to win.
Are there any incentives for bitcoin miners and users?

Comment: Have you seen any evidence that this is indeed the case? Can you link to it?

Comment: Yeah, I have active research in this area. I will link to my paper ASAP.